# Different ways to print quotation within print() statement only using double quotation in Python

Tags: python

How do I use escape characters inside print() statements to print a quote? Here is what I mean -

```
author = "Flamingo"
quote = "The universal expression is Gagalulu"
```

I wanted to print - Flamingo once said, "The universal expression is Gagalulu."
I have use format() to achieve the result

```
print(author, "once said, ", '"{}."'.format(quote))
```

But I could not achieve the same result using \ method and using a double quote (" ")
Can somebody guide me, please?

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is: you have achieved the desired result, and it's perfectly fine Python. Why do you want to achieve it in another way?

Comment: Why couldn't you use  a slash?

Comment: @Sayse I am learning, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative using an f-string and single quotes for the string itself:

```
f'{author} once said, "{quote}"'
```

---

If you want to see a use of `\"` instead, this would work:

```
f"{author} once said, \"{quote}\""
```

---

Note: f-strings are basically an alternative for using the `.format(...)` method of a string, perhaps with some slight limitations, though not in practice. The names between curly braces `{}` have to match actual variable names in the code for f-strings to work.

Comment: This does not answer the question "How do I use escape characters inside print() statements to print a quote?"

Comment: @Sayse To quote myself: "An alternative ...". Sometimes, giving an alternative may be better than answering the question to the letter.

Comment: I'd agree an alternative *is* good, when there is an actual problem to be solved, there shouldn't be anything wrong with the OP's escaping but its unclear why that doesn't work as intended currently. The OP has already found a suitable workaround, their question appears to be about escaping characters.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do this is by using single quotes and an f-string (if you're using python 3.6 or later) or .format():

```
print(f'{author} once said, "{quote}"')
print('{} once said, "{}"'.format(author, quote))
```

---

Other options that I normally would not use are listed below:

```
print("Flamingo once said, \"The universal expression is Gagalulu.\"")
print('Flamingo once said, "The universal expression is Gagalulu."')
print("""Flamingo once said, \"The universal expression is Gagalulu.\"""")
print("""Flamingo once said, "The universal expression is Gagalulu." """)
```

To add `author` and `quote`, you can:

```
print(f"""{author} once said, \"{quote}\"""")
print(author + """ once said, \"""" + quote + """\"""")
print(author + ' once said, "' + quote + '"')
print("""{} once said, \"{}\"""".format(author, quote))
print("""%s once said, \"%s\"""" %(author, quote))
```

Or, also possible:

```
from string import Template
s = Template('$author once said, "$quote"')
print(s.substitute(author=author, quote=quote))
```

Comment: With triple quotes, you don't even need the first backslash. And if there would be a space or period after the closing double quote, you wouldn't need a backslash there either.

Comment: @00 Never heard of those, I'll add it

Comment: I wouldn't do that: there are already way too many options, which makes picking the right one (if there is one) hard. I'm guessing the OP's still somewhat of a beginner in Python, so it may make more sense to suggest just a few very common alternatives. If you *do* want to make a comprehensive answer about Python string formatting with quotes inside the string, you could create a self-answered question, e.g. "What are the various ways of using quotes (single or double) inside a string in Python".